# Antd: Is it possible to move the table row expander inside one of the cells?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an antd table where the data inside one of the columns can get pretty large. I am showing this data in full when the row is expanded but because the cell with a lot of data is on the right side of the screen and the expander icon is on the left side of the screen it is not very intuitive. What I would like to do is move the expander icon inside the actual cell so that the user knows they can click the + to see the rest of the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can and you have to dig a little deeper their docucmentation...

According to [rc-table docs](https://github.com/react-component/table) you can use `expandIconColumnIndex` for the index column you want to add the `+`, also you have to add `expandIconAsCell={false}` to make it render as part of the cell.

See [Demo](https://codepen.io/kossel/pen/veMVyP)

Comment: Thank you, that works beautifully, and the link to the component doc is helpful. I have been only looking at the Ant Design docs themselves.

Comment: Coming to this in 2020, doesn't seem necessary to add expandIconAsCell={false}, but I'm still using antd 3.20.1.

Comment: "expandIconAsCell" doesn't work now. I think they deprecated it, unable to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can make any column expendable.
First add `expandedRowKeys` in your component `state`

```
state = {
    expandedRowKeys: [],
  };
```

Then you need to add these two functions `onExpand` and `updateExpandedRowKeys`

```
<Table
    id="table-container"
    rowKey={record => record.rowKey}
    className={styles['quote-summary-table']}
    pagination={false}
    onExpand={this.onExpand}
    expandedRowKeys={this.state.expandedRowKeys}
    columns={columns({
        updateExpandedRowKeys: this.updateExpandedRowKeys,
    })
    }
    dataSource={this.data}
    oldTable={false}
/>
```

This is how you need to define the function so
that in `expandedRowKeys` we will always have 
updates values of expanded `rowKeys`

```
onExpand = (expanded, record) => {
    this.updateExpandedRowKeys({ record });
  };

  updateExpandedRowKeys = ({ record }) => {
    const rowKey = record.rowKey;
    const isExpanded = this.state.expandedRowKeys.find(key => key === rowKey);
    let expandedRowKeys = [];
    if (isExpanded) {
      expandedRowKeys = expandedRowKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
        if (key !== rowKey) acc.push(key);
        return acc;
      }, []);
    } else {
      expandedRowKeys.push(rowKey);
    }
    this.setState({
      expandedRowKeys,
    });
  }
```

And finally, you need to call the function `updateExpandedRowKeys`
for whichever column you want to have the expand-collapse functionality available.
Even it can be implemented for multiple columns.

```
export const columns = ({
    updateExpandedRowKeys,
  }) => {
    let columnArr = [
      {
        title: 'Product',
        key: 'productDes',
        dataIndex: 'productDes',
        className: 'productDes',
        render: (text, record) => (
          <span onClick={rowKey => updateExpandedRowKeys({ record })}>
            {text}
          </span>
        ),
      }, {
        title: 'Product Cat',
        key: 'productCat',
        dataIndex: 'productCat',
        className: 'product-Cat',
      }]
    }
```